# Merge request: fedora tags

Tags: discussion, status-declined

Please merge the following tags into the [fedora](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fedora) tag, as I don't see any real usage of having a different flag for nearly every single fedora version released:

- [fedora8](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fedora8)
- [fedora9](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fedora9)
- [fedora13](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fedora13)
- [fedora14](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fedora14)
- [fedora15](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fedora15)
- [fedora17](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fedora17)

And merge [fedora-ds](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/fedora-ds) into [389-ds](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/389-ds) as the product actually has been renamed/replaced.

Comment: Yeah, that is getting out of control. What's the story with Fedora DS/389 DS? What's the new name?

Comment: Are there any substantial differences between Fedora 8 & Fedora 17? If not this makes some degree of sense since Fedora releases major versions about as regularly as every other OS releases patches...

Comment: There are major differences between the releases. If we'd merge all Fedora tags, we'd also need to merge all Windows XP/2000/Vista/7/8 tags. And yes - the differences between distinct Fedora releases are big enough to legitimate different tags.

Comment: If we start merging those where do we stop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that having different tags for different OS version *is* a good thing. Each one has it's one quirks and bugs that may or may not have been fixed or changed between major releases. While the underlying systems may be alike they are different systems that need to be treated differently.

That said they probably should be Fedora-$Version not Fedora$Version.

Comment: OK. I'm not a Fedora administrator, and I'm really amazed that it changes THAT much between releases. Change the OP to status-declined.